# WooCommerce payment plugin credit card form template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add new payment method on wooCommerce so I added new payment method to checkout options on admin side.

On the client side, I created new template for displaying credit card form. I want to see this form on new page after "checkout now" button clicked.

How can I integrate my template with WooCommerce? I didnt find any example like that.

I am new on Wordpress and I am sorry for bad English because its not my native language.

Thanks in advance.